# How to correct Python-Tensorflow has no attribute error ''getdlopenflags'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Hello everyone I am new to scripting and trying to work on something for a studio project in architecture. I have a windows pc.

I am trying to run gantools via ganbreeder. I made sure to download the correct version of python. After running the pip install of gantools it prompted me that I needed to meet the requirements of installing a verion of tenserflow.I used pip install for tenserflow and I was able to install gantools. Now I'm trying to execute this line

```
"gantools --username (blank) --password (blank) --nframes 40 --keys 90fbd0ada957a5d30c4a 6157e59ab08fa404088c b319a920db2764c4f560 400393b3714e18dc d7b65ec5c3f2941f4830594a"
```

but I get the error

```
"C:\Users\dimit>gantools --username (blank) --password (blank) --nframes 40 --keys 90fbd0ada957a5d30c4a 6157e59ab08fa404088c b319a920db2764c4f560 400393b3714e18dc d7b65ec5c3f2941f4830594a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dimit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\dimit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dimit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\gantools.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\dimit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gantools\cli.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gantools import biggan
  File "c:\users\dimit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gantools\biggan.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
  File "c:\users\dimit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "c:\users\dimit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    _default_dlopen_flags = sys.getdlopenflags()
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'getdlopenflags'
```

can someone please help me with solving this error?

Also is there a way to use gantools using your own images to create morphing animations between images? Or is there a less complicated method. Please share!

Thank you

Comment: It seems that you are running tensorflow on a Windows machine. ```getdlopenflags``` is supported only on Unix platform. see [sys.getdlopenflags](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.getdlopenflags) documentation.  Are you using 32-bit version of Python ? TF needs 64-bit.